# Java input file validation

Tags: java, input, try-catch

Is there a way to use a try/catch statement to ask the user to enter a file, if the user enters the wrong filename, the program will ask two more times, and then exit with an exception? How could I loop? Because once the user enters the wrong filename the program throws the exception immediately.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Main {
    static String[] words = new String[5];
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("enter file name:");
        String fileName = kb.next();

        try {

            File inFile = new File(fileName);
            Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(fileName));

        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }    

    }
```

Comment: Why not just use a loop then and increment the count in the catch block?

Comment: It's a good idea to use inFile.exists() rather than use try / catch for program flow.

Comment: how could make the catch portion execute once a counter reaches a specific number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope it's obvious that the FileNotFoundException is thrown by the Scanner constructor. So why use it until you're sure the file exists? You shouldn't create the Scanner object till you got the correct file!
To implement this idea use this in your try block:

```
//read file name from stdio
File inFile = new File(fileName);
int i = 0;
while(!inFile.exists() && i++ < 2 ){
        //read file name from System.in;
        inFile = new File(fileName);
}
Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
```

Comment: why are you reading files from two different places.... System.in is the keyboard and that's the user input. If I'm not mistaken what you mean by "stdio" is standard input, and that is also the keyboard, so why repeating  twice? also the file is open once you declare = new File(filename) or with the Scanner?

Comment: stdio and System.in are the same thing. As far as I understood you want to ask the user again for the file name in case he does a mistake the first time. So, my code snippet can be "read" like this: 
Ask the user for the file name, if the filename doesn't exist, ask the user for the filename 2 more times.

Answer (score 2):

So you don't want it to throw any kind of error when the user enters the wrong filename, right? If so, then I think this is what you want:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        try {
            File inFile = new File(fileName);
            Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
            break;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            if(i == 2){
                Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                System.exit(0);
            }
            else
                continue;
        }
    }
```

if the user enters the correct file name, it will break out of the loop. If not, it checks to see if the loop is on it's third iteration. If it is, (that means the user has tried and failed twice), it prints the error and exits the program. If the loop isn't on it's third iteration, it continues with the loop and re-prompts the user.

Comment: I have not tried it yet, but this one seems very straight forward.. Thanks guys

Comment: This meets your requirements, but I'd stress that it is not an elegant solution. Others have pointed out the use of File.exists as much cleaner solution to your problem.  Just my thoughts on the subject

Answer (score 0):

assuming you create a boolean fileIsLoaded = false, and set that to true. You can create a loop

```
for(int i=0;i<2 && !fileIsLoaded; i++) {
//your try/catch goes here
}
```

Enclose all of the code within your current main within that loop (with the boolean created beforehand). Finally, you can check the boolean afterwards in case all tries failed.

Comment: and then if the boolean is still false throw an exception.. is that what you mean?

Comment: yep. with a throw new XXX(), such as throw new RuntimeException("Too many invalid filenames");